# Splitting/nesting _.flow with lodash (or ramda)

Tags: functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js

I have two objects, one describes the `features` of a location, the other describes the `prices` of those features.

```
features = {
  improvements: [...] // any array of many id's
  building: {} // only one id, may be undefined
}
prices = {
  id_1: 10,
  ...
}
```

I want to iterate over `features` and collate all the `prices`. **Sometimes `features.building` will be `undefined`, sometimes `features.improvements` will be empty**.

[Additional code/workbench on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FeistyGrippingTrial)

I can do this with `lodash` in this manner:

```
result = _(features.improvements)
  .map(feature => prices[feature.id])
  .concat(_.cond([
    [_.isObject, () => prices[features.building.id]]
  ])(features.building)) // would like to clean this up
  .compact()
  .value();
```

I'm interested in writing this in a more functional manner, and I ended up with:

```
result = _.flow([
  _.partialRight(_.map, feature => prices[feature.id]),
  _.partialRight(_.concat, _.cond([
    [_.isObject, () => prices[features.building.id]]
  ])(features.building)),
  _.compact,
])(features.improvements)
```

I still have to almost secretly call `features.building` mid stream, which feels awkward to me.

What I'd like to get to is (pseudocoded):

```
flow([
  // maybe need some kind of "split([[val, funcs], [val, funcs]])?
  // the below doesn't work because the first
  // flow's result ends up in the second

  // do the improvement getting
  flow([
    _.map(feature => prices[feature.id])
  ])(_.get('improvements')),

  // do the building getting
  flow([
    _.cond([
      [_.isObject, () => [argument.id]]
    ])
  ])(_.get('building')),

  // concat and compact the results of both gets
  _.concat,
  _.compact,
])(features); // just passing the root object in
```

Is it possible? How would a more seasoned FP-Programmer approach this?

I'm open to solutions written with `lodash-fp` or `rambda` (or anything with good docs I can try to understand) since those probably give cleaner code because they're more functionally-orientated/curried than standard `lodash`.

Comment: The reason why your code gets complicated and requires `undefined` to indicate the absence of data is the use of product types where you should use [unions](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/) (of products).

Comment: I'm unsure how that is supposed to fit in my code. It's a custom type? I am using Vuex as a data store which prefers to use POJO and primitive types.

Comment: Wouldn't I still run into the same problem? `union({id:_} | not_set)`, I'd still have to filter out my `not_set` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lodash**

Here is a solution that uses `_.flow()`:

1. Convert the features to an array using `_.values()`, `_.flatten()`, and `_.compact()` (to ignore `building` when `undefined`).
2. Convert to an array of `id`s with `_.map()`.
3. Get the values with `_.at()`.

```js
const { values, flatten, compact, partialRight: pr, map, partial, at } = _;

const fn = prices => _.flow([
  values,
  flatten,
  compact,
  pr(map, 'id'),
  partial(at, prices)
])

const prices = {
  i_1: 'cost_i_1',
  i_2: 'cost_i_2',
  i_3: 'cost_i_3',
  i_4: 'cost_i_4',
  b_1: 'cost_b_1',
};

const features = {
  improvements: [
    {id: 'i_1'},
    {id: 'i_2'},
    {id: 'i_3'},
    {id: 'i_4'},
  ],
  building: {
    id: 'b_1'
  },
};

const result = fn(prices)(features);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**lodash/fp**

```js
const { values, flatten, compact, map, propertyOf } = _;

const fn = prices => _.flow([
  values,
  flatten,
  compact,
  map('id'),
  map(propertyOf(prices))
])

const prices = {"i_1":"cost_i_1","i_2":"cost_i_2","i_3":"cost_i_3","i_4":"cost_i_4","b_1":"cost_b_1"};
const features = {"improvements":[{"id":"i_1"},{"id":"i_2"},{"id":"i_3"},{"id":"i_4"}],"building":{"id":"b_1"}};

const result = fn(prices)(features);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

**Ramda**

1. Get the values, flatten, and filter `undefined`s using `R.identity`.
2. Get the `id` props with `R.map`.
3. Use a fliped `R.props` to get the ids values from `prices`

```js
const { pipe, values, flatten, filter, identity, map, prop, flip, props } = R;

const propsOf = flip(props);

const fn = prices => pipe(
  values,
  flatten,
  filter(identity),
  map(prop('id')),
  propsOf(prices)
);

const prices = {"i_1":"cost_i_1","i_2":"cost_i_2","i_3":"cost_i_3","i_4":"cost_i_4","b_1":"cost_b_1"};
const features = {"improvements":[{"id":"i_1"},{"id":"i_2"},{"id":"i_3"},{"id":"i_4"}],"building":{"id":"b_1"}};

const result = fn(prices)(features);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion using Ramda.

I suggest breaking the problem into smaller functions:

1. Get the price ids for all improvements: `getImprovementIds`
2. Get the price id for the building: `getBuildingId`
3. Get the price ids for everything: `getPriceIds`
4. Get the price for given price id: `getPrice`

**Examples**

```
getImprovementIds(features); //=> ['id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3']
getBuildingIds(features);    //=> ['id_5']
getPriceIds(features);       //=> ['id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_5']
getPrice(prices, 'id_2');    //=> 20
getPrice(prices, 'foo');     //=> 0
```

Once you have a list of price ids, it is easy to convert that list into a price list:

```
map(getPrice(prices), ['id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3', 'id_5']); //=> [10, 20, 0, 50]
```

**Complete Example**

```js
const {propOr, ifElse, hasPath, path, always, compose, sum, map, flip, converge, of, concat} = R;

const features = {
  improvements: ['id_1', 'id_2', 'id_3'],
  building: {
    id: 'id_5'
  }
};

const prices = {
  id_1: 10,
  id_2: 20,
  id_5: 50
};

/**
 * Take a features object and return the price id of all improvements.
 * @param {object} features
 * @return {array} array of ids
 */
const getImprovementIds = propOr([], 'improvements');

/**
 * Take a features object and return the price id of the building (if any)
 * @param {object} features
 * @return {array} array of ids
 */
const getBuildingId =
  ifElse(hasPath(['building', 'id']),
    compose(of, path(['building', 'id'])),
    always([]));

/**
 * Take a features object and returns all price id of all improvements and of the building (if any)
 * @param {object} features
 * @return {array} array of ids
 */
const getPriceIds = converge(concat, [getImprovementIds, getBuildingId]);

/**
 * Take a prices object and a price id and return the corresponding price
 *
 * @example
 * getPrice(prices, 'id_2'); //=> 20
 *
 * @param {object} prices
 * @param {string} id
 * @return {number}
 */
const getPrice = flip(propOr(0));

const getPriceList = (prices, features) =>
  map(getPrice(prices), getPriceIds(features));

console.log(
  getPriceList(prices, features)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```